# Why can we not attach same LayoutManager Object with multiple RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Getting following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LayoutManager
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@f8f0a is already
>   attached to a RecyclerView: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

following is the code(Kotlin Code Snip)

```
val layoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    layoutmanager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL

    val parentView = view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.solid_fill_picker)
    val recyclerView1 = parentView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.theme_color_palette1)

    recyclerView1.layoutManager = layoutmanager
val layoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    layoutmanager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL


    val recyclerView2 = parentView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.theme_color_palette1)

    recyclerView2.layoutManager = layoutmanager
```

Comment: Is this question about layout manager implementation details? :) If the error explicitly says "don't do this, but do this instead" it means this behavior is by design. Just create two instances of a layout manager.

Comment: set the layout manager in xml. Problem solved

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin
indirectly it implies to LayoutManager Implementation detail specifically for 're-using the object reference for multiple recyclerView Objects'

Comment: @vikasjha I don't undestand you.. The main question is, why are you trying to reuse the layout manager? What gave you the impression that you can/should do that? The `RecyclerView` was designed by developers in that way. You are not supposed to reuse the layout manager object and the error message explicitly says that. More information here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/247185b98675b09c5e98c87448dd24aef4dffc9d/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java.

Comment: You are defining the same variable twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `LayoutManager` keeps the reference to `RecyclerView` inside of itself, and when you try to use the same `LayoutManager` again - it gives you that error. One `LayoutManager` can manage only one instance of `RecyclerView`. If you want to use `LayoutManager` with the same params and not create another one from scratch - you can create `LayoutManager` factory and get each time new `LyaoutManger` with the same params.

Comment: `LayoutManager keeps the reference to RecyclerView`. Does it mean we should detach the LayoutManager from the RecyclerView when the view is destroyed?